# resolve raspbian clone no-ip conflict

Tags: redirect, raspbian, noip

I cloned raspbian SO by "SD card copier".
In that SO I configured no-ip web-server redirection (no-ip duc).

When I start raspbian clone in other location it steal ip redirect from it's original twin.

Using original SO with ethernet, and configured no-ip duc with ethernet, I figured out to solve problem by starting cloned SO with wifi, but it not worked!

The problem is:
how to prevent cloned-SO (when started) steals ip-redirect of origonal-SO.
Someone has an idea to do that?
Tank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (but maybe exists some simpler).

Concept:
add a bash script to crontab and verify if router MAC-address match with specific router.

The bash script is (**note: chmod +x**):

```
#!/bin/bash

# SCRIPT DOES IF ROUTER MATCH EXPECTED MAC ADDRESS

# -- EDITABLE PART --
# function todo if TRUE
function_MATCH () {
  echo "MAC adresses match!"
}

# function todo if FALSE
function_MISMATCH () {
  echo "it's not as expected!"
}


# CHANGE VALUE WITH YOUR ROUTER MAC ADDRESS
EXPECTED="55:55:55:55:55:55"

# -- END EDITABLE PART --

# get "arp -a" string of router:
arp=$(arp -a 192.168.1.1)
# extract MAC adress
MAC=${arp##*at }
MAC=${MAC% [*}
if [ "$MAC" = "$EXPECTED" ];
 then function_MATCH
 else function_MISMATCH
fi
```

This is a generic function callback (function_MATCH or function_MISMATCH).
To use this script to activate no-ip service only if router match desired one, change function_MATCH() with following one:

```
function_MATCH () {
  echo "MAC adresses match!"
  sudo noip2
}
```

then, save script (where you prefer) and edit crontab by calling, in terminal:

```
$ crontab -e
```

finally, call script in crontab adding it at the end.

for example (be carefull to add right script-path):

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /home/user/scripts/router_verificator.sh
```

Note: no-ip service need a connection to update ip-redirect.
doing verification after 60secs from SO-start prevent no connection
available.

I know, its quite complicated.
If someone has a smarter solution.. tank you.